# How to insert data from another table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a "member" table:

```
| id | name | inbox | sent |
```

and i have a "inbox" table:

```
| id | from | to | subyek | message |
```

and i have a "sent" table too:

```
| id | to | from | subyek | message |
```

how do I want to fill in the inbox and sent fields from the member table with the amount of data from the inbox table and the sent table?

Comment: `SELECT INTO` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: `INSERT` + `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For existing rows in `member`, assuming that `to` and `from` columns in `inbox` and `sent` tables contain  `id` values from the `member` table, then we could get a count of related rows from `inbox` and `sent`, and store the counts into columns in the `member` table, with something like this:

```
UPDATE `member` m 
   SET m.inbox = ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `inbox` i ON i.to   = m.id )
     , m.sent  = ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `sent`  s ON s.from = m.id )
```

---

This example is making all kinds of unwarranted assumptions... what is meant by "amount of data", the relationship between the inbox and sent tables to the member table, ...

Without example data and the expected end result, we are just guessing at the specification, and any SQL we propose is just a guess.

Performance of correlated subqueries can be problematic on large sets when suitable indexes are not available. There are other query patterns that will achieve an equivalent result.